# Split list into several columns in R

Tags: json, r, list

in the WEBSITE column of my dataset, there are lists (from a json file). Here is a sample of the column WEBSITE:

```
> dataset$WEBSITE[[1]])
[1] "list(Headers = list(MaxTopicsRootDomain = 30, MaxTopicsSubDomain = 20, MaxTopicsURL = 10, TopicsCount = 3), Data = list(ItemNum = 0, Item = \"https://mywebsite.com/\", ResultCode = \"OK\", Status = \"Found\", ExtBackLinks = 1398, RefDomains = 452, AnalysisResUnitsCost = 1398, ACRank = 4, ItemType = 3, IndexedURLs = 1, GetTopBackLinksAnalysisResUnitsCost = 5000, DownloadBacklinksAnalysisResUnitsCost = 25000, DownloadRefDomainBacklinksAnalysisResUnitsCost = 25000, RefIPs = 323, \n    RefSubNets = 273, RefDomainsEDU = 0, ExtBackLinksEDU = 0, RefDomainsGOV = 0, ExtBackLinksGOV = 0, RefDomainsEDU_Exact = 0, ExtBackLinksEDU_Exact = 0, RefDomainsGOV_Exact = 0, ExtBackLinksGOV_Exact = 0, CrawledFlag = \"True\", LastCrawlDate = \"2017-10-05\", LastCrawlResult = \"HTTP_404_NotFound\", RedirectFlag = \"False\", FinalRedirectResult = \"\", OutDomainsExternal = \"5\", OutLinksExternal = \"11\", OutLinksInternal = \"162\", OutLinksPages = \"1\", LastSeen = \"\"... <truncated>

> dataset$WEBSITE[[2]])
[2] "list(Headers = list(MaxTopicsRootDomain = 30, MaxTopicsSubDomain = 20, MaxTopicsURL = 10, TopicsCount = 3), Data = list(ItemNum = 0, Item = \"http://www.website.uk\", ResultCode = \"OK\", Status = \"Found\", ExtBackLinks = 254, RefDomains = 76, AnalysisResUnitsCost = 254, ACRank = 9, ItemType = 3, IndexedURLs = 1, GetTopBackLinksAnalysisResUnitsCost = 5000, DownloadBacklinksAnalysisResUnitsCost = 25000, DownloadRefDomainBacklinksAnalysisResUnitsCost = 25000, RefIPs = 75, RefSubNets = 56, \n    RefDomainsEDU = 0, ExtBackLinksEDU = 0, RefDomainsGOV = 0, ExtBackLinksGOV = 0, RefDomainsEDU_Exact = 0, ExtBackLinksEDU_Exact = 0, RefDomainsGOV_Exact = 0, ExtBackLinksGOV_Exact = 0, CrawledFlag = \"True\", LastCrawlDate = \"2017-12-14\", LastCrawlResult = \"DownloadedSuccessfully\", RedirectFlag = \"False\", FinalRedirectResult = \"\", OutDomainsExternal = \"2\", OutLinksExternal = \"2\", OutLinksInternal = \"19\", OutLinksPages = \"1\", LastSeen = \"\", Title = \"Dedic... <truncated>

 > dataset$WEBSITE[[3]])
[3] "list(Headers = list(MaxTopicsRootDomain = 30, MaxTopicsSubDomain = 20, MaxTopicsURL = 10, TopicsCount = 3), Data = list(ItemNum = 0, Item = \"http://www.website.uk\", ResultCode = \"OK\", Status = \"Found\", ExtBackLinks = 254, RefDomains = 76, AnalysisResUnitsCost = 254, ACRank = 9, ItemType = 3, IndexedURLs = 1, GetTopBackLinksAnalysisResUnitsCost = 5000, DownloadBacklinksAnalysisResUnitsCost = 25000, DownloadRefDomainBacklinksAnalysisResUnitsCost = 25000, RefIPs = 75, RefSubNets = 56, \n    RefDomainsEDU = 0, ExtBackLinksEDU = 0, RefDomainsGOV = 0, ExtBackLinksGOV = 0, RefDomainsEDU_Exact = 0, ExtBackLinksEDU_Exact = 0, RefDomainsGOV_Exact = 0, ExtBackLinksGOV_Exact = 0, CrawledFlag = \"True\", LastCrawlDate = \"2017-12-14\", LastCrawlResult = \"DownloadedSuccessfully\", RedirectFlag = \"False\", FinalRedirectResult = \"\", OutDomainsExternal = \"2\", OutLinksExternal = \"2\", OutLinksInternal = \"19\", OutLinksPages = \"1\", LastSeen = \"\", Title = \"Dedic... <truncated>
```

My dataset looks like this:

```
COLOR       |    SIZE        |   WEBSITE
Blue        |    13456       |   list(Headers = list(MaxTopicsRootDomain = 30, MaxTopicsSubDomain = 20, MaxTopicsURL = 10
Green       |    17487       |   list(Headers = list(MaxTopicsRootDomain = 30, MaxTopicsSubDomain = 20, MaxTopicsURL = 10,
Red         |    65438       |   list(Headers = list(MaxTopicsRootDomain = 30, MaxTopicsSubDomain = 20, MaxTopicsURL = 10, To
```

**My goal is to turn each json node into a dedicated column to make my dataset look like this:**

```
COLOR       |    SIZE        | MaxTopicsRootDomain | MaxTopicsSubDomain | MaxTopicsURL
Blue        |    13456       | 30                  | 20                 | 10
Green       |    17487       | 30                  | 20                 | 10
Red         |    65438       | 30                  | 20                 | 10
```

I tried a method, but I not sure I m on the right way...

```
dataset$WEBSITE <- as.character(dataset$WEBSITE) #character needed for a strsplit()
hello <- strsplit(dataset$WEBSITE, split = ",")
hello <- data.frame(COLOR = rep(dataset$Color, 
                            sapply(hello, length)), 
                            WEBSITE = unlist(hello))
```

Any help very gratefully received!

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you post a reproducible example. That said, you might want to look at the `jsonlite::flatten` function....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the anwser.

It's probably not perfect, but it works!

```
dataset_2 <- do.call(rbind, dataset$WEBSITE)
dataset_2 <- cbind(dataset[c("COLOR")], dataset_2)
dataset <- merge(dataset,dataset_2,by="COLOR")
dataset <- unique (dataset)
```